# Parse Point Cloud to Reference Geometry

Tags: pdal, opengl, pcl, vtk

I have a large point cloud in ASCII format that is aligned to the coordinate system I require. I also have a range of either .igs splines or reference surfaces .stp that I would like to filter the point cloud to in order to create new filtered point cloud groups with the name of the nearest reference object.

Is there a tool I can use in VTK, PCL, OpenGL etc that can parse the point cloud down rapidly? The cloud would be quite large at around 20gb and I would like to associate 20 reference features to the subsequent parsed cloud.

Would anyone have guidance for me to pursue this?